Python dataframe string extraction from a column and assign it to required columns
I have a dataframe with field OverallRatio, and other six ratios (Lets say A, B, C, D, E, F) had to be calculated based on this, looking at the index splitting by the ;. For example the calculation for A,B, C, D, E,F should be based as:
enter image description here
OverallRatio               A          B       C      D        E         F
1:0.25; 3:0.33; 5:0.5     0.25        0       0.33    0       0.5       0
5:0.25; 6: 0.75            0          0        0      0       0         0.75
1:0.5; 6:0.33              0.5        0        0      0       0         0.33
2:0.25; 4:0.5              0          0.25     0      0.5     0         0


Try this:
data = {'OverallRatio': ['1:0.25; 3:0.33; 5:0.5', '5:0.25; 6:0.75', '1:0.5; 6:0.33', '2:0.25; 4:0.5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['A'] = 0
df['B'] = 0
df['C'] = 0
df['D'] = 0
df['E'] = 0
df['F'] = 0

# Calculate ratios
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ratios = row['OverallRatio'].split('; ')
    for ratio in ratios:
        idx, value = ratio.split(':')
        idx = int(idx)
        value = float(value)
        if idx == 1:
            df.at[index, 'A'] = value
        elif idx == 2:
            df.at[index, 'B'] = value
        elif idx == 3:
            df.at[index, 'C'] = value
        elif idx == 4:
            df.at[index, 'D'] = value
        elif idx == 5:
            df.at[index, 'E'] = value
        elif idx == 6:
            df.at[index, 'F'] = value

print(df)

Output:
            OverallRatio     A     B     C    D     E     F
0  1:0.25; 3:0.33; 5:0.5  0.25  0.00  0.33  0.0  0.50  0.00
1         5:0.25; 6:0.75  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.25  0.75
2          1:0.5; 6:0.33  0.50  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.33
3          2:0.25; 4:0.5  0.00  0.25  0.00  0.5  0.00  0.00


Try:
x = df["OverallRatio"].str.extractall(r"(\S+):([^;]+)").droplevel(1).reset_index()
x = (
    x.pivot(index="index", columns=0, values=1)
    .fillna(0)
    .rename_axis(columns=None, index=None)
)
x.columns = [chr(ord("A") + (int(c) - 1)) for c in x.columns]
print(pd.concat([df, x], axis=1))

Prints:
            OverallRatio     A     B     C    D     E      F
0  1:0.25; 3:0.33; 5:0.5  0.25     0  0.33    0   0.5      0
1        5:0.25; 6: 0.75     0     0     0    0  0.25   0.75
2          1:0.5; 6:0.33   0.5     0     0    0     0   0.33
3          2:0.25; 4:0.5     0  0.25     0  0.5     0      0

